# delete a line from a list of lines

Tags: python

I am reading a csv into a list, and I need to delete an entire line from the list under a specific condition:

```
import csv

thefile = []

def dowork():
    sourceFile='e.csv'
    CleanFile(sourceFile)

def CleanFile(sourceFile):
    global thefile
    thefile=list(csv.reader(open(sourceFile, 'rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"'))
    for line in thefile:
        if line[3]=='':
            #here's where i need to delete line from thefile
```

how would i delete `line` from `thefile`?

Comment: One quick thing: `if line[3]='':` won't work; you're using assignment (`=`) rather than comparison (`==`). Also, are you sure you want to compare it to the empty string? That's never going to be true. If you're looking for the equivalent of the C `line[3] == '\0'` the best way to do that is `len(line) == 3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the index of `line` within `thefile`. Once you have that, it's easy. And the way you get that is with [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate).

```
def CleanFile(sourceFile):
    global thefile
    thefile=list(csv.reader(open(sourceFile, 'rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"'))
    for i, line in enumerate(thefile):
        if line[3]=='':
            del thefile[i]
```

However, it's worth asking whether you actually need to delete it. For example, could you just filter it out like this?

```
def CleanFile(sourceFile):
    global thefile
    thefile=[line for line in 
             csv.reader(open(sourceFile, 'rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')) 
             if line[3] != '']
```

Or, depending on what you're doing with the data, maybe it makes even more sense to just skip over lines where `line[3] == ''` at output or calculation time. Or, even better, don't make a list in the first place; just leave csv.reader as an iterator—then you can stick a filter in front of it via `itertools.ifilter`, or a generator expression. In fact, that's as simple as just changing two characters:

```
def CleanFile(sourceFile):
    global thefile
    thefile=(line for line in 
             csv.reader(open(sourceFile, 'rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')) 
             if line[3] != '')
```

Of course this makes no sense if you need, e.g., random access to `thefile`. But if you're going to iterate over it line by line, this is probably the best solution. (Except that `thefile` shouldn't be a global; it should be passed around from function to function as needed.)

Comment: thank you so much! can you please tell me why you do not use  thefile[i].pop()?

Comment: `thefile[i].pop()` just removes the last character from the line, it doesn't delete the entire line. (Try it and see.)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Yes, that's almost the same as `del thefile[i]`, except that it returns the deleted value. At that point, it's really just a matter of style, but I think it's clearer to use `del` when the point is to delete something, `pop` when the point is to fetch-and-delete something.

Answer (score 1):

Try using filter:

```
def CleanFile(sourceFile):
   global thefile
   thefile=list(csv.reader(open(sourceFile, 'rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"'))

   def f(x): return x[3] != ''
   thefile = filter(f, thefile)

   return thefile
```

Comment: `filter` is one of those functions that Guido frowns on and would deprecate if anyone would let him, because it can be always be replaced by a comprehension (or generator expression), and because it explicitly turns any iterable into a list whether you want to or not (although `itertools.ifilter` solves that), so I try to avoid teaching it to new Python users.